# When is a question worth asking?

Tags: discussion

to my mind came the question, when a question is actually worth asking.

I.e. if I'm stuck in a programming situation with a question/problem, that I could figure out by myself trough trial and error, even tough this would take much longer for me (maybe up to 1/2h or 1h or more) to find the solution to the problem by myself than by just asking experienced programmers on stackoverflow (who sometimes answer within 3 minutes on a well structured and percisely described problem) and probably will need much less time to find the solution.

The kind of problems I think about are for example:

- linker problems arising from source-code designed and structered in a bad way (i.e. definitions in header files)
- logic errors in algorithms, which I have to track down (it could be helpful to explain the algorithm to someone else and let him have a glance on it)
- not within mapped region segfaults because of bad-designed loops

When will a question start to annoy people and to what extend can such questions be asked unless getting annoying.

Comment: I'd be happy if I could find solutions within the hour to the problems I ask on SO. Searching is learning, do it yourself for as long as possible.

Comment: Logic errors are often the result of not defining the problem clearly enough to begin with. So if you can create a minimal example and include a couple test cases where your algorithm fails, you will have done most of the work already.

Answer (score 0):

A question is worth asking if, and only if, it is on topic, clear, specific and includes the fruits of adequate relevant research.

That is, it is worth asking if there is a reason to up vote it (or at least, not to down vote it) and no reason to close it.

There is nothing more to be said.